# Read all file from a directory (with different cwd)

Tags: python

Following code is to read all files in a directory,But the problem is my cwd is `/home/kumarswamys/Adobe`(where i stored readdir.py) but the i want to read the files in `/home/kumarswamys/Adobe/download`, but I am not able read those file because cwd is `/home/kumarswamys/Adobe`,It says no such file or directory

I tried join the path but it not working,can anyone help me please....?
     readdir.py

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 import os

 path = '/home/kumarswamys/Adobe/download'  
 for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
 for file in files:
    print file
    f=open(file, 'r')
    f.readlines()
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import glob
path = '/home/kumarswamys/Adobe/download/*.py'
files=glob.glob(path)
for file in files:
    f=open(file, 'r')
    f.readlines()
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`os.path.join(subdir, filename)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to get path:

```
>>> os.path.join('/home/kumarswamys/Adobe/download', 'filename.txt')
'/home/kumarswamys/Adobe/download/filename.txt'
```

---

```
import os

path = '/home/kumarswamys/Adobe/download'  
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(subdir, filename) # <-----
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
```